# Matrix Class input operator overload

Tags: c++, matrix, operator-overloading

Hello I have an assignment to implement a Matrix class using pointers.

```
    class matrixType{
      private:
        int **matrix;
        int numRows;
        int numColumns;
      public:
        istream& operator >>(istream& ins, const matrixType& source);
    }
```

I'm having trouble with the input operator for this!  For some reason this operator overload is not making sense to me, but I also have a function that also allows for user input which isn't an overload.

```
    void matrixType::setMatrix(){
      int i,k,value;
      cout << "Be prepared to enter values to be inserted into your matrix: " << endl;       
        for(i=0; i<rowSize; i++){
           for(k=0; k<columnSize; ++k){
             cout << "Value [" << i << "][" << k << "]: ";
             cin >> value;
             matrix[i][k]=value;
           }       
         }       
      cout << endl;
    }
```

Can someone help me on the input operator?
Thank you!

Comment: C++ doesn't have "input operator". It is called "(bitwise) shift operator".

Comment: *"I'm having trouble"* What kind of trouble? *"it's not making sense to me"* Where, exactly, it doesn't make sense to you? *"Can someone help me on the input operator?"* **What is your question?**

Comment: This site is supposed to be about answering questions. So far your question seems to be "can someone help me?". The answer is, "sure, somebody, somewhere on the planet can help you". Which won't be helpful. Ask specific questions, then you'll get specific answers.

Comment: For starters, you should **always** check that the result of an input operation was successful, e.g., `if (std::cin >> value) { ... } else { ... }`. You might also want to tell us, what doesn't work.

Comment: @SigTerm I asked for someone to help me with the input operator.  I ended up getting an answer so it was obviously enough for someone to figure it out.  It isn't my problem if one person doesn't understand my question.  No offense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input operator overloading function allows you to use the object of a class or struct directly into function like `cin`. This way you can directly ask for all inputs by writing a single statement that inputs the object and it will input all the values itself.

The program should be like

```
class matrixType{
      private:
        int **matrix;
        int numRows;
        int numColumns;
      public:
        istream& operator>>(istream& input, const matrixType& source)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<numRows;i++)
                  for(int j=0;j<numColumns;j++)
                           input>>source.matrix[i][j];
            return input;
         }     
    }
```

Now You can input the values directly using cin like this

```
matrixType A;
cin>>A;
```